# Retrieve values from View and save it in a list in ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I want to save values selected or entred in my view (in the form) in a local variables.

So I create a liste in my view Model:

```
public List<Gamme> ListG = new List<Gamme>();
```

I want now to RETRIEVE values from the view and put in the objet of this liste :

```
public Gamme A = new Gamme (........);
```

This is the view where the values are entred :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Anouar")) { %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
<fieldset class="parametrage">
    <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

    <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" onclick="test();"/>Poste Initial<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final</div>


     <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
    <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Position)%></div>
    <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PostePrecedentSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
    <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PosteSuivantSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>


    <div><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  /></div>

    </fieldset>
```

**UPDATE :**
FlowViewModel :

```
private static Dictionary<string, Gamme> userGammes;

        public static Dictionary<string, Gamme> UserGammes
        {
            get
            {
                if (userGammes == null)
                {
                    userGammes = new Dictionary<string, Gamme>();
                }
                return userGammes;
            }
        }
```

and the Controller of the View :

```
public ActionResult Save(Gamme gamme)
         {
             UserGammes.Add("currentUserID", gamme);

         }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, instead of saving in the database you can put on a static dictionary ... and clear it when no longer needed using something like "Singleton" pattern:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Gamme> userGammes;

public static Dictionary<string, Gamme> UserGammes
{
    get 
    {
       if (userGammes== null)
       {
          userGammes = new Dictionary<string, Gamme>();
       }
       return userGammes;
    }
}
```

and in your controller

```
public ActionResult Save(Gamme gamme)
{
    UserGammes.Add("currentUserID", gamme);
    // ... do stuff
}
```

Comment: @anouar in your view you must have a form that will send the post to your Controller

Comment: So I will use BeginForm ?? and UserGammes is not known in the controller ?

Comment: try to use a Controller Generation (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+C) to generate your Controller and Views from your model Gamme, then you can put the UserGammes object in this Controller

Comment: No,,,I can't ! because they are bind to another views and controllers

Comment: Please Check my Update,,,I follow your instructions